# Perform Memory Allocation To Store Data Obtained In Interrupt Handler

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, interrupt, portaudio

I am writing a program that uses PortAudio to get audio input from the computer into my program. PortAudio, in their [Writing a Callback](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html) tutorial, says that the callback is triggered as an `Interrupt Handler`, and explains that code written in the callback needs to not do:

> memory allocation/deallocation, I/O (including file I/O as well as console I/O, such as printf()), context switching (such as exec() or yield()), mutex operations, or anything else that might rely on the OS

The problem I'm having is figuring out how would I go about processing the audio coming from the callback without being able to use `malloc`. My current (and working) callback looks like this.

```
int Audio::paCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer, unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData ) {
    // Cast data passed through stream to our structure.
    auto *in = (uint16_t *) inputBuffer;
    // Get number of audio channels, for instance stereo would be two
    int numberOfChannels = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice())->maxInputChannels;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; i++) {
        auto storedStream = (uint16_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint16_t) * (framesPerBuffer + 2));
        storedStream[0] = uint16_t(i);
        storedStream[1] = uint16_t(framesPerBuffer);
        for (int j = 0; j < storedStream[1]; j++) {
            storedStream[j + 2] = in[numberOfChannels*j+i];
        }
        audioQueue->push(&storedStream);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know I shouldn't be using `malloc`, so how would I go about fixing this?

While looking for examples of code, I found that Audacity, a free audio editing software, uses PortAudio. I have looked at [Audacity's PortAudio callback](https://github.com/audacity/audacity/blob/master/src/AudioIO.cpp) (line 2391 in `AudioIO.cpp`), and all they do is call two functions. In the second function, they call `alloca`, which allocates memory.

Is it ok to call functions from an interrupt handler that then do memory allocation, or would the functions also be executed within the interrupt context?

Comment: One technique is to estimate the maximum amount of memory needed, and allocate that before even setting up the interrupt handling/callback.   Then your interrupt handler simply initialises/reinitialises that previously allocated memory.   A second technique is for your interrupt handler to dispatch a message/signal of some form asynchronously to another thread (so your interrupt handler can complete, and the other thread completes the work in slow time).

Comment: No, you can not call malloc() in the interrupt handler. Imagine what happens when the interrupt happens when you are already inside the malloc()? The interrupt handler will try to aquire mallocs mutex and block till it gets released, which never happens. As Peter says you have to allocate beforehand. That is if you are really in an interrupt. Your Audacity URL points to `DoSoftwarePlaythrough` which is probably not what calls your callback.

Comment: Note that `alloca()` is a compiler extension that allocates storage in the stackframe of the function. That is thread and interrupt safe but also automatically release the storage at the end of the function.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Interesting note, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally to avoid dynamically-allocated memory, we'll employ the use of various 'static containers.' Things like a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of pre-allocated and reserved data, or a blit buffer (two static buffers, where new data is added to one buffer, while previously-added data is processed from a second buffer. Periodically their roles are 'swapped' when all the data in the 'processing' buffer is empty).  In both cases, it helps to know the 'maximum' amount of data you're likely to need, and pre-allocate that much data.

> Is it ok to call functions from an interrupt handler that then do memory allocation, or would the functions also be executed within the interrupt context?

This really depends on your target platform.  Sometimes avoiding dynamic memory allocation is very important, and sometimes on modern embedded platforms, the concern is quite a bit overblown.